# How do I allow Hangouts to access camera and Mic in Ubuntu BQ M10 OTA 11?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, m10, google-hangouts

There's no URL bar to click on for making the access and in the settings it won't work as well.

Comment: It used to work for me, using the default browser (rc-proposed, before OTA11 was released), but when checking now in order to write an answer I am having the same problem you have. Weird.

Comment: And after updating my M10 again (to r122) and restarting it works again. I get a dialog in the middle of the screen asking about the permissions. Switching between front and rear camera also works, but not very reliably.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to install google chrome browser

Then login --> Install the hangout extension from chrome app store.

Launch it --> If it asks for login again inside the app.

The app starts by default when google chrome is launched.

Alternatively you can pin the app in the launch bar. When the app is open it's icon is automatically present in the launch bar. Right click and click pin.

Also you can click on ubuntu terminal and type hangout. The icon gets visible. You can click on it and the app launches.

I f your camera and mic are set properly then the app automatically captures them.

Comment: Chromium isn't available for Ubuntu Touch, and Chromium doesn't work either so far. Apart from that the question wasn't about pinning a shortcut to Hangouts, but about giving access to microphone and camera.

Answer (score 0):

You should get a dialog in the middle of the screen asking about the permissions when you start a video call.

If it doesn't work, try updating and/or restarting your tablet.